# Unable to remove CSS bullets from list

Tags: html, css

I'm fighting with CSS and can't figure out how to remove bullets.  Yeah, I know this sounds easy, but hear me out.  I have another external CSS file from our corporate office that has styles that are getting in the way and I can't for the life of me figure out how to override them.  I've tried the !important token and it doesn't work either.  I'm using chrome and the inspector hasn't yet helped me figure out what's causing it.  Anyway, here's my code which works great stand-alone, but once I put the corporate CSS file in there, the stupid bullets come back.  Ugh!

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li>First</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Does the corporate CSS have !important?

Comment: Use Firebug (or similar), inspect the element and it will tell you the sources of the styles defines for that element.

Comment: !important is a blunt tool and is usually an indicator that you need to re-factor your CSS.

Comment: So `<ul style="list-style-type:none !important;">` fails?

Comment: The corporate CSS doesn't have !important.

Comment: Agreed.  I typically never use the !important token.  Secondly I'm not allowed to refactor the corporate CSS as much as I'd like to just throw it away.  It's a mess.

Comment: Yes. the <ul style="list-style-type:none !important;"> fails.  It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This sounds like more of an issue with [CSS specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity). You can't "override" the other styles, per se, you can merely create additional styles which are more specific. Without knowing what the other CSS looks like, there are generally three ways to do this:

### Inline styles

Exactly like you have in your example. These are *most* specific, so they're guaranteed to work, but they're also guaranteed to be a pain in the neck to work with. Generally, if you're using these, something needs to be fixed.

### Add an `id` attribute to the unordered list,

Then use the `id` as a selector in your CSS. Using an `id` as a selector is more specific than using a `class` or an element type. It's a useful tool for cutting through a bunch of styling that you might be inheriting from somewhere else.

```
<ul id="the-one">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>

ul#the-one {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

### Wrap all of *your* HTML in a `div` with the `id` attribute set.

This is what I usually do. It allows me to use that `div` with it's `id` in my CSS styles to *make sure* my styles always take precedence. Plus, it means I only have to choose one meaningful `id` name, then I can just style the rest of my HTML as I normally would. Here's an example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Some text goes here</p>
</div>

div#wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div#wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Using that technique is a pretty good way to make sure that you spend most of your time working on your own styles and not trying to debug somebody else's. Of course, you have to put `div#wrapper` at the beginning of each of your styles, but that's what [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  I tried this with an embedded style sheet in my head tags just like you explained.  My html also looks like what you've explained.  When I go into Chrome's inspector, the Computed Style shows "list-style-type: none;" and it says the style came from "div#wrapper ul".

Comment: I figure out what the problem was.  It was a backgound-image style being used as a bullet in the corporate CSS.  Once I found that I was able to apply the necessary background-image:none; style appropriately.  Done!  Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: @noctufaber did you apply it to the ul? li? I'm doing it to all of them and it's not working.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, I was trying to change the CSS for a joomla website, and finally found that the li had a background image that was a bullet... (the template was JAT3). This is the code:

```
.column ul li {
  background: url(../images/bullet.gif) no-repeat 20px 7px;
  ...
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with a joomla template language switcher.

Comment: +1 I had this problem, putting the list-style-type: none; on the <li> solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the rule you're trying to override is on the UL, rather than the LI. I've seen that rule applied to LIs, and overriding the UL as you have above would have no effect.

Comment: Yes.  It's definitely on the UL tag.

Comment: Perfect, this was my issue I had it on the li instead of the ul d'oh! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My situation is similar to the one described by @fankoil: my inherited css had

```
main-divname ul li{
  background-image:url('some-image.png');
}
```

to get rid of this for a specific ul, I gave the ul an id

```
<ul id="foo">
...
```

and in the css, turned off background image for this particular ul

```
ul#foo li {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

So to add some clarification to some previous answers:

- list-style-type is on ul
- background-image in on li

Answer (score 0):

It's better if instead of having the style inline you call it using a class:

```
<ul class="noBullets">

.noBullets {
list-style-type:none !important;
}
```

If you can't find the style that's overwriting yours, you can use the [!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm) property. It's better to first inspect your code online using chrome or firefox's Inspect element (or firebug).

EDIT:

Accordnig to your comment, the style comes from div#wrapper ul. Did you try:

```
div#wrapper ul {
list-style-type:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I totally agree with you.  I'm only putting the CSS inline for demonstration.  The problem is our corporate CSS file is preventing my style from asserting itself.

Comment: Yup.  Tried the !important property.  It doesn't work (at least in this case).

Comment: did you use firebug? It has to tell you what's overwriting it!

Comment: I'm using Chrome's inspector.  It's telling me that the computed style is list-style-type:none;  Unfortunately it still has annoying little bullets.

Comment: I wish I could put this on the web, but it's for a local intranet.

Comment: I would apply list-style-type:none to ALL the elements before the ul, and then see if the problem is still there. You could also try overwriting with something like white bullets and 0 padding... or even white background and negative padding!

Answer (score 0):

The Trick is very simple:

HTML get that:

```
<ul id="the-one">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Style get that:

```
ul#the-one {list-style-type: none;}
```

But, the next two options will blow your mind:

```
li {width: 190px; margin-left: -40px;} // Width here is 190px for the example.
```

We limit the width and force the li paragraph to move left!

See a Awesome example here: http://jsfiddle.net/467ovt69/

Answer (score 0):

Good question; it's odd how the bullets show in IE even with the list-style:none;

This is the code that removed the bullets:

```
/* media query only applies style to IE10 and IE11 */
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* removes bullets in list items for IE11*/ 
    li {
        list-style-position: outside;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the following line of code in your css:

```
.targeted-class-name>ul>li>a:before {
    content: "•";
}
```

That was the culprit in my case

Answer (score -1):

i think you could solve also your problem by wrapping text in your list-item with span then used something like this:

```
ul>li:nth-child(odd) > span:before {
    display:none;
}

ul>li:nth-child(even) > span:before {
    display:none;
}
```

> Odd and even are keywords that can be used to match child elements whose index is odd or even, and display=none will do the trick to by not displaying element before the span element.